# Clear Navigation back stack and Recreating activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation, android-darkmode

I'm developing an app that has a `LoginFragment` and `HomeFragment`.
And I'm using jetpack navigation component for handling fragment navigations.
In the first, after that user completed the login proccess in `LoginFragment` I call `popBackStack()` then I navigate user to `HomeFragment`.
The problem appear when the user clicked on `dark mode` button.
I call `recreate()` on activity.
And I need to Restore the NavHost again But I cleared the `StartDestination` of that navHost.

What Can I do to solve this problem?

***Note***: I tried using `popUpTo` ; but that not worked for me.

Comment: That isn't how you are supposed to do login. Did you read the [very specific guide to doing login with the Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login)?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thanks for the link, I read this link just now and I think I realized what should I do. Please send this link as an Answer to accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using login as the start destination of your graph as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination):

> Note: An app might have a one-time setup or series of login screens. These conditional screens should not be considered start destinations because users see these screens only in certain cases.

Instead, follow the [guide for doing Login in the Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login) and navigate to your login screen conditionally (i.e., only when the user is not logged in).